# Identify the following surface as a connected sum of either or projective planes with holes

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

The picture looks like a [image]connected sum of 4 tori with two holes. Am I correct or is there any other algorithm that I don't know.

P.S: I am sorry for giving a picture like this but I got this question in an old question paper and didn't get a better way to represent it.

Comment: 1. Is it embedded in 3-D space? 2. Are those handle-like things strips or handles? Also, the two holes in the middle, are they tubes or just two holes in $D^2$? 3. Since you mentioned that this question comes from an old question paper, could you please add the original description/picture/anything of this question to make this clearer?

Comment: Could you please correct your question, which obviously has a word omitted? Also, you should include the question in the main body of the post, not just in the title. Since you have the two twisted strips, this must be a surface-with-boundary. Hence, it is a disk with 4 holes and two twists. There are no tori. I'm not cognizant enough to say what difference it makes that one of the twists connects the outside of the disk to one of the holes.

Comment: It can't be orientable.

Comment: Actually this is the question that I got in the paper and didn't have any more info. I can email the professors though.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a connected sum of projective planes with a few boundary components. This follows from the classification of compact surfaces and the fact that, in the picture you give, there exists a loop (around one of the half twisted handles) which can not be covered by orientation preserving charts. Hence the whole surface is nonorientable.

Comment: How many components are there then?

Comment: How many connected sum of projective planes and how many boundary components are there?